# CKEditor4: Make Text Differ from its HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I add `StrInsert` plugin to my CKEditor. It basically adds a button, which in my editor, is labeled `CRM Field`. [image]

What the button does is it will append a value to my editor. For example: when I click `$[FIRST_NAME]` from the dropdown, it will append the text `${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}`to my editor.

Why did I name the dropdown `$[FIRST_NAME]` instead of`${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}`? Because I want the `HTML` to be `<p>${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}</p>` while the `text` shown in the editor is `$[FIRST_NAME]`[image: (**Please see** [screenshot_2][2] **to better understand the problem**)]

As seen in `screenshot_2`, the `HTML`shown  underneath is exactly what I want, but instead of showing the text `${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}` I want the editor to show the text `$[FIRST_NAME]`

My question is, how can I make the `HTML` differ from the `text` shown in the editor for some reserved keywords?

Comment: The plugin link [https://github.com/activore/strinsert](https://github.com/activore/strinsert) --I couldn't add more than 2 links to my original post

Answer (score 1):

Is a workaround fine? If you can post- and preprocess the data, the solution is simple. Preprocess the data incoming by replacing `${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}` with `$[FIRST_NAME]` and before saving, do the opposite.

For a fancier method with more complicated replaces but has a nicer UX, I'd use widgets with code like this:

```
<p data-real="${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}">$[FIRST_NAME]</p>
```

You'd create a plugin that defines that every P with a `data-real` attribute as a widget. Then before saving you'd convert them into the simple P you like and when loading you'd convert the simple P back to the widget. The benefits here is that the user can't accidentally edit the text and that drag and drop is easy. The replaces should be pretty easy with jquery for example.

I don't know why you'd want them to be block level though, I'd imagine that variables such as these would be nicer inline - but that's up to your requirements.

Widget documentation at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nenotleps.
When a user confirms the editors input, just replace `$[FIRST_NAME]` with `<p>${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}</p>` and if some data is load to the editor do it the other way round.

You can get the current editor content in html with `editor.getData()`, where editor is your ckeditor instance