# Output Text With Different HTML Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, templates

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
HTML:
<p>ABC</p>

Output:
DEF
```

I asked this because I want to make an email template where the HTML part **must** have `<p>${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}</p>` (where `${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}` is a variable). The variable is to be replaced by the actual value later. However, the user must not see it on the screen; instead they will see `${FIRST_NAME}` There is another constraint: I can't give `id` or `class` attributes to the element containing ther word that I want to replace.

I originally asked this question here:
[CKEditor4: Make Text Differ from its HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306394/ckeditor4-make-text-differ-from-its-html), but nobody seemed familiar with CKEditor. So, it's even better if there's an easier way to do it with CKEditor.

Comment: I was thinking about making the keyword/ `text` `display: none` and then put an image to cover the place that previously had the `text`. That way, the HTML didn't change although the display changed for this particular page that had the `CSS` But, I could not do that since there was no unique `id` or `class` to select from.

Comment: really hard to understand what your goals are and why you can't use string replacement methods at server

Comment: @charlietfl I work in a CRM company. We help our clients reach out to their customers automatically, and email broadcasting is one of our features. This Text Editor is for our clients to make an email template for their customers (newsletters, promotion, etc). We want our clients to make, for example,`Hi ${first_name} ${last_name}, blah blah blah` However, the variables to be replaced with the actual value later is `${__VCG__VAL__FIRST_NAME}`,etc. It's longer, and we don't want to confuse our clients.Plus, it doesn't look so good. But we want them to know that it's a variable. I hope it helps

Comment: If you're making a template, you'll need something (possibly server-side) that processes the template. String replacement is likely your best bet, as @charlietfl suggests. If you want to include variables, using ${first_name} ${last_name} is fine, provided you specify to your clients what var (placeholder) names are valid and their format.

Comment: you still haven't identified your exact problem , why can't these variable name translations be made at server?

Comment: @charlietfl That's a good question. I was just receiving request from somebody else who worked with servers. I will ask him if he can just make the variable translations at server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I put together a while ago that seems like it's what you're looking for.

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/5bY59/)**

Comment: Great plugin! But he doesn't have an HTML example or any download page for the script. I'm having a hard time understanding PHP. Is this how you link the script to the HTML file ? `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext/master/jquery.ba-replacetext.js"></script>` I tried adding the script and your demo to my HTML, but it didn't work.

Comment: You'll want to download the script and upload it to the folder where your other scripts are located. Your linking is correct, it just may not be connecting because it's on github. Try This `<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPTS/jquery.ba-replacetext.js "></script>`

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle to show a little better. Also, keep in mind, that this is all happening client side, it is possible to do this dynamically on the server side using PHP... using the `str_replace()` function.