# jQuery plugin doesn't work : replaceText

Tags: jquery

I'm following tutorials to use this plugin from [here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/spotlight-jquery-replacetext--net-17905) , but I can't make it run.

I tried the simplest code possible, so it would be obvious if there's a typo.

Could you tell me where's the mistake?

**--Edit--** 
Thanks for suggesting other options to change the text. However, that's not the issue. Please read my previous posts why I needed this plugin:

[CKEditor4: Make Text Differ from its HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306394/ckeditor4-make-text-differ-from-its-html/26335341#26335341) and [Output Text With Different HTML Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309133/output-text-with-different-html-format/26346834#26346834)

Here's the **DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test h1').replaceText(/\btext\b/gi, "TEXT" );
});
```

```html
<!--jQuery 2.1.1 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- plugin link -->
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext/master/jquery.ba-replacetext.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should at first load the jQuery lib then it's plugin.

Comment: I changed it, still no difference though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem in your snippet is the pluggin src is not working. If you just copy what is in the js file and use this:

```
$('#test *').replaceText("text", "TEXT");
```

Then it does work.

```js
(function($) {
  '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

  // Method: jQuery.fn.replaceText
  // 
  // Replace text in specified elements. Note that only text content will be
  // modified, leaving all tags and attributes untouched. The new text can be
  // either text or HTML.
  // 
  // Uses the String prototype replace method, full documentation on that method
  // can be found here: 
  // 
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace
  // 
  // Usage:
  // 
  // > jQuery('selector').replaceText( search, replace [, text_only ] );
  // 
  // Arguments:
  // 
  //  search - (RegExp|String) A RegExp object or substring to be replaced.
  //    Because the String prototype replace method is used internally, this
  //    argument should be specified accordingly.
  //  replace - (String|Function) The String that replaces the substring received
  //    from the search argument, or a function to be invoked to create the new
  //    substring. Because the String prototype replace method is used internally,
  //    this argument should be specified accordingly.
  //  text_only - (Boolean) If true, any HTML will be rendered as text. Defaults
  //    to false.
  // 
  // Returns:
  // 
  //  (jQuery) The initial jQuery collection of elements.

  $.fn.replaceText = function(search, replace, text_only) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var node = this.firstChild,
        val,
        new_val,

        // Elements to be removed at the end.
        remove = [];

      // Only continue if firstChild exists.
      if (node) {

        // Loop over all childNodes.
        do {

          // Only process text nodes.
          if (node.nodeType === 3) {

            // The original node value.
            val = node.nodeValue;

            // The new value.
            new_val = val.replace(search, replace);

            // Only replace text if the new value is actually different!
            if (new_val !== val) {

              if (!text_only && /</.test(new_val)) {
                // The new value contains HTML, set it in a slower but far more
                // robust way.
                $(node).before(new_val);

                // Don't remove the node yet, or the loop will lose its place.
                remove.push(node);
              } else {
                // The new value contains no HTML, so it can be set in this
                // very fast, simple way.
                node.nodeValue = new_val;
              }
            }
          }

        } while (node = node.nextSibling);
      }

      // Time to remove those elements!
      remove.length && $(remove).remove();
    });
  };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test *').replaceText("text", "TEXT");
});
```

```html
<!--jQuery 2.1.1 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need the selector to search for `#test h1` instead of only `#test`

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue with this plugin according to the tutorial. But, I tried adding `h1` to my code snippet above, still didn't work

Comment: as described in the examples you need to use a regex as the first parameter i.e. `$('#test h1').replaceText(/\btext\b/gi, "TEXT" );`

reference http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/examples/replacetext/

Comment: In the second link, under `Usage` it says either way would work. But, I've changed my snippet above as you suggested, still doesn't work though

Comment: okay, it is working with this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r3qhwm96/

maybe something else is not quite right?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working now. Turns out I have to download the source, I can't just link it like that, because Github is not CDN. Thanks anyway. +1 for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myLmg80e/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').replaceText( "text", "TEXT" );
});
```

Comment: Please see my Edit in the original post above. Thanks!